# Is it safer to place a exe.config file outside IIS root path

Tags: .net, iis, web-config, file-structure

in my web application , i need to use a .exe.config file which contains sensitive like passwords.

Is it better to place it outside the IIS root path in order to reduce the threats ?

I know IIS does not serve config file but i keep hearing it's always dangerous writing plain text passwords in config files...
Thanks in advance for your advices.

Comment: having plain password in a file is bad idea as you already hear.  Why dont you consider using a database for this?

Comment: I can't use databases. 
As far as i know, the database connectionstring with login and password is also in the config file, so the threat remains unchanged no ?

Comment: no.. even if they get hold of your database login and password they still have no clue on the table names, table structure, what table has what etc etc... Hence they cannotdo much anyways.. Also even if they do get to know about the table structure they still cannot query it unless you allow them to or unless there is any design flaw like `SQL Injection`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We use **Registry** for storing passwords safely. You can encrypt your passwords with machine key and store in Windows Registry.